# Cannot assign values to $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables, variable-assignment

```
session_start();
//Yes i did call session start but forgot to add it here
print $userID.":::";

$_SESSION['id'] = $userID;
$_SESSION['email'] = $userEmail;
$_SESSION['password'] = $userPassword;
$_SESSION['picture'] = $userProfilePicture;
print "ID: ".$_SESSION['id'];
```

Result:
1:::ID:

I cannot assign any of my variables to the session variables in my code, why is that? I've done it before and the code is identical except for the variables

Comment: Forgot to call session_start() first ?

Comment: Have you called `session_start`?

Comment: Did you make sure your variables are what you think they are?

Answer (score 4):

In order for sessions to work on a PHP page you have to call the session_start(); function at the top of every page you want to access the sessions.

Comment: I didn't realize it was on all pages using the the Session, i thought it was only where you assigned them. Thank You!